# ERROR: could not create unique index DETAIL: Key (id)=(3105115) is duplicated

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I am facing this problem on PostgreSQL, PgAdmin 4. I tried to alter one table.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ALTER COLUMN some_column type NUMERIC;
```

But I keep getting error

> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(3105115) is duplicated.

But when I select that table `Select count(id) from mytable where id = 3105115`
I get count = 1.

Did anyone face this problem before?

Would be appreciated for any help.

Comment: What is the original data type of the column?

Comment: Original is integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely experiencing data corruption.

Try to

```
REINDEX INDEX mytable_pkey;
```

or whatever the unique index is called. That will likely give you a similar error message.

You can find entries with duplicates with:

```
SET enable_indexscan = off;
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;
SELECT id, count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

After removing these duplicates, your operation should succeed.

As always with data corruption:

1. export the whole cluster and import it to a new cluster to get rid of any corruption.
2. check your hardware